# Can't understand how array's elements are passed to a function's argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have a function that i can understand.

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i< array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
```

When we call that function lets say `forEach([1,2,3,4,5], console.log);`
The code replaces the word action with the word console.log in the body. And everything works like a charm. Right ?

But in this case with the anonymous function i get confused.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;

forEach(numbers, function(number) { sum += number; });
```

In that case we have an anonymous function as an argument. How the anonymous function takes the element one by one from the array numbers, and puts it in it's argument (number)?.

I could make it somehow more easy to understand:

```
var FindSum = function (number) {
  sum += number;
};

forEach(numbers, FindSum);
```

But i am still confused with the argument number. How does the `FindSum` function receives a number?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking, but yes the final code below is valid

Comment: Im asking how the code understands that the array's elemets should be put inside the argument number.

Comment: The two cases are virtually identical. In both cases, you pass a function reference. In the first, you pass the name of a host method (*console.log*), in the second you pass a function expression (which can have a name if you want) so the only thing that has a reference to it is the *action* parameter of the *forEach* function. Other than that, everything is the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same as in the first example:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i< array.length; i++)
        action(array[i]); // array[i] is the argument
}
```

So `number`is `numbers[i]`

```
var numbers = [1,2,3];
var FindSum = function (number) {
  sum += number;
};

forEach(numbers, FindSum); // equals FindSum(1); FindSum(2); FindSum(3);
```

Comment: The thing i dont really undestand is the process of how number becomes numbers[i]. :/

Comment: In your `forEach`method you loop through the `numbers`array and then call the action which is `FindSum` with `numbers[i]/array[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
forEach(numbers, function(number) { sum += number; });
```

Explained in really simple manner:

1. forEach takes an array (numbers) and a callback function (anonymous one, it can be named too)
2. forEach then passes each number in numbers to anonymous function
3. Then you sum "sum" and the current value of the number